# Export descriptives from Jamovi to R

Tags: r, jamovi

I am using Jamovi to work on some variables of a data set from a excel file.

```
jmv::descriptives(
  formula = country ~ `voted`,
  data = bd,
  bar = TRUE,
  missing = FALSE,
  mean = FALSE,
  median = FALSE,
  sd = FALSE,
  min = FALSE,
  max = FALSE)
```

When I import the code and try to execute the code to obtain the graphics, I have the following errors:

```
Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In mean.default(x, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(x, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
4: In mean.default(x, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
5: In var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
6: In var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
7: In var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

I  am missing something?

Comment: I guess you meant `voted ~ country`

Comment: @akrun I have the same problem.

Comment: Can you show the `str(bd)`

Comment: It is too long to show it here.

Comment: @akrun, please see the link: https://pastebin.com/RVixzYt2

Comment: I didn't see the `country` and `voted` column in the link

Comment: Sorry, there it is now: https://pastebin.com/TdXad9Qg. country relatees to three countries (Poland, Russia and Czech Republic) and voted relates if the individuals voted, not voted or are not elegible to vote in their country. I'm a beginner in R.

Comment: If you check the `marshalFormula`, the `permitted = c("numeric", "factor")`, but your column is character.  Can you convert to `factor` and do this again.  i.e. `bd$country <- factor(bd$country)`

Comment: Does it work for you

Comment: No, after do the bd$country<- factor(bd$country), R seems not to work properly.

Comment: Sorry, if you can show the dput of some example to test it would be great as I am able to get results correctly with `mtcars` data mentioned in their documentation

Comment: So, I will let you the steps: 1) import the excel file to R; 2) change the columns names to 'country' and 'voted'; 3) do the str(bd); 4) do the factor(bd$country) and then tried to run the jamovi code with voted~country. Nothing happens...

Comment: after doing the factor: https://pastebin.com/av75YJsi

Comment: can u do `dput(droplevels(head(bd,30)))` and get the output in pastebin

Comment: Here it is: https://pastebin.com/Hh9nrijX. I think that is what you want. Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: It is actually working for me

Comment: I posted my output as a solution.  Are you still getting the error with that 30 records

Comment: I used the `packageVersion('jmv')#
[1] ‘1.2.23’`

Comment: Can you please confirm whether you are getting error with those 30 records

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230665/discussion-between-sandra-silva-and-akrun).

Comment: Hello, I was offline.  Let me know when you are online

Comment: @akrun I'm online now. Let's move to a chat?

Answer (score 0):

Two issues with solutions I see:

1.) formula = country ~ `voted`, should be formula = 'voted', country since the variable to the left of the Tilda is the dependent variable.

2.) You should assign data = data.

Further assistance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZomeS0tLxY

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).